# How do I deal with Mac Mail acting improperly?

Tags: mac, email

This is a MacBook Pro M1 running Ventura. When I open 'mail' the screen begins to populate with hundreds of blank mail forms so much so that the spinning ball will not allow me to reach the safari bar and am forced to force quit. I want to delete mail completely from this Mac, that was the object when this situation began. My husband tries to send reply emails that are in forms online and they default to "mail."

I have tried my best to ask questions on google and work with those answers but they fail when they tell me to go to the upper right hand corner in mail and click uninstall, the death ball is there. Took advise to go into the terminal and into folders... I do not have enough information to know what to do in those places..so here I am hoping someone can help me resolve this issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent it [or any Mac app] trying to re-open its last saved state, by holding  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  as you launch.

You cannot delete or uninstall Apple's built-in apps from a Mac.

Answer (score -1):

Either wait long enough (just have to do it once).

Or disconnect from the internet - disable wifi or pull the plug and then open Mail.  Again you may have to wait for it to time out.